# Android setPixel(int x, int y, int color) makes my program crash how do I fix it?

Tags: android, colors, bitmap, imageview

```
ImageView testImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)testImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
bitmap.setHasAlpha(true);
bitmap.setPixel(10, 10, Color.argb(255,255,255,255));
```

My program crashes immeadiately when I try to run this code inside my main activity inside the onCreate

What am I doing wrong? all i want to do is change one pixel in the bitmap

Comment: Read (and include) the exception message.

Comment: LogCat is one of your best tools for solving bugs. Get used to reading and understanding what it's telling you. One of the first things to check for is any "Caused by..." comments in the Text column. This will also have a line number telling you where in your code the problem has occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the exception? as I remembered by default the bitmap is immutable means you cannot modify it. create a copy of the bitmap is required.

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
    ImageView testImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    options.inMutable = true;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.testImage,
                    options);
    bitmap.setPixel(10, 10, Color.argb(255,255,255,255));
```